# Distinct in Elastic Search for Java Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to get distinct city name from some pincode index in elastic search it contains pincode and cityname so there a multiple pincode with same city name.

So what happening is while searching with cityname, I am getting multiple record so Right now I have done a temporary.

fix like getting all record and then take do distinct in that.

```
public List<FcData> getCityFuzzy(String city){

        SearchQuery searchQuery= (new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()).withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("city",city)
                .prefixLength(1)
                .fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO)
                ).build();


        List<FcData> fcData=jestElasticsearchTemplate.queryForList(searchQuery,FcData.class);

        fcData=fcData.stream()
                .filter(distinctByKey(pr -> Arrays.asList(pr.getCity())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return fcData;
    }
```

private static  Predicate distinctByKey(Function keyExtractor) {

Map seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        return t -> seen.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;

}

I have also try aggregation but that is also not working for me I am using elastic search `6.4` with `SpringBoot`.

Comment: Can you filter by pin code?

Comment: @Tim ya It can be filtered by pincode.